# Can't import a class from a python package

Tags: python, class, package

I created a private python package with this structure:

```
   python_package
       utils
          __init__.py
          module1.py
          module2.py
```

And inside the module1.py file there is a class `Class1`

Now when I download this package in another project using pip, I can't import `Class1` using

`from utils import Class1`

Am I missing something ?

Also the `__init__.py` file contains the following lines :

```
from .module1 import *
from .module2 import *
```

Answer (score 1):

try this if you are not able to access the class directly

```
import filename
object=filename.class1()
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably in another project you need to import it like this:

```py
from python_package.utils import Class1
```